# sql update - two tables - update column with incremental value depending on column in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

table `CLASS (class, count)`

```
 class     count
--------- -------
 first     3
 second    2
 third     4
```

table `STUDENT (class, id_no, name)`

```
 name     id_no   name
-------- ------- ------
 first    1       abc
 first    2       bcd
 first    3       def
 second   1       xyz
 second   2       tay
 third    1       m
 third    2       n
 third    3       o
 third    4       p
```

Total number of rows in `STUDENT` table is always equal to the count in `CLASS` table.
eg: first entry in `CLASS` table shows the class name as "first" and count as 3. 
so it will have 3 entries in `STUDENT` table.

Now the problem is - the `id_no` column of student table has '0' zero in all rows.

It should be updated as shown above.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This only work if no repeat names for a class. Otherwise you need create an unique ID first

```
 WITH cte as ( 
       SELECT class, 
              row_number() over (partition by clas  order by name ) as id,
              name
       FROM Student
 )
 UPDATE Student 
 SET id_no = cte.id
 FROM  cte
 WHERE Student.class = cte.class 
   and Student.name  = cte.name
```